# Finding actual URL from <a href="#"

Tags: javascript, html, vba, href

A page source snippet has the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return changepageforpagerlink(10);" class="enabledPagerLink">Next</a>
```

I know that the "#" is a placeholder that is handled by Javascript on the page.  I believe the relevant Javascript snippet is:

```
function changepage(start) {
    makerequest('/ajax/inventory_search.php', collectformvalues(start));
}

// do not flash the search options when using next/prev - just when the search is changed
function changepageforpagerlink(start) {
    doEffectOnAjax = false;
    changepage(start);
    return false;
}
```

I need to know if there is a way that I can submit a URL and have the next page's page source returned. Is there a URL that is submitted at all in the above example?

My environment is VBA.  I'm not using a browser, just communicating with the server. One thing I thought of is to mimic the "makerequest" function, but I don't know how to do that or if would even work.  I know at the heart it's all just sending text to the server and receiving text back so I would think there is a way. . .

Bottom line is that I need to access the page source from the next page via VBA and not using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery to achieve this:

```
function changepage(start) {
makerequest('/ajax/inventory_search.php', collectformvalues(start));
}
```

changes to

```
function changepage(start) {
$.ajax({
type:POST,
url:"/ajax/inventory_search.php",
}).done(function(){
//do anything when it's done.
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do this without JQuery - just VBA.  I decided to use a browser instance and that works.  Not what I wanted to do, but in the end effective.